# MySQL - How do I use CONCAT in ALTER TABLE?

Tags: mysql

How do I concatenate in `ALTER TABLE`?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$sql1="ALTER TABLE t1 ADD iod = CONCAT('10.1234','/',id)";
```

`id` is a different column in the same table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misusing `ALTER TABLE`.  It is intended to modify the data definition (structure) of a table, not its values.

If you want to modify the values in a table, you should use one of the following types of queries:

- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE

Answer (score 1):

Use `update` after you add a column to fill it out:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD iod varchar(150)
UPDATE t1 SET iod = CONCAT('10.1234','/',id)
```

Any new rows that you add would have to include the proper value of `iod`.  Computed columns would solve this, but I don't think they're available on MySQL.